# VB multi-dimensional array throwing out of bounds exception

Tags: excel, multidimensional-array, indexoutofrangeexception

I'm currently working on a small piece of vba software that is doing some excel worksheet manipulation. I'm currently running into an indexOutOfRangeException during the first iteration of the loop in the code below. I've run this in debug and can see that the array has a value at the requested index but I keep getting this exception.

```
 Private Sub AddReportQuestions(ByRef ReportName As String, ByRef i As Integer, 
                               ByRef domainStart As Integer, ByRef domainEnd As Integer, 
                               ByRef xlReportWorkSheet As Excel.Worksheet,
                               ByRef xlQuestionWorkSheet As Excel.Worksheet)
    Dim row As Integer
    row = 0

    Dim maxPrintableRow = ((domainEnd - domainStart) * 4) + 7
    Dim maxQuestions = (domainEnd - domainStart) + 1

    Dim reportRange = xlReportWorkSheet.Range(xlReportWorkSheet.Cells(7, (i * 10) + 1), xlReportWorkSheet.Cells(maxPrintableRow, (i * 10) + 10))
    Dim questionRange = xlQuestionWorkSheet.Range("C" & domainStart & ":I" & domainEnd)

    Dim questionArray(maxQuestions, 7) As Object
    Dim reportArray(maxPrintableRow + 1, 10) As Object

    questionArray = questionRange.Value

    For j = 0 To maxQuestions
        ' Question
        reportArray(row, 0) = questionArray(j, 0)

        ' Resize Row Height
        xlReportWorkSheet.Rows(row + 7).RowHeight = 45

        row += 1

        ' Response and Comment
        reportArray(row, 0) = questionArray(j, 1)
        reportArray(row, 2) = questionArray(j, 4)

        ' Resize Row Height
        xlReportWorkSheet.Rows(row + 7).RowHeight = 45

        row += 1

        ' Likelihood and Consequence
        reportArray(row, 0) = "Likelihood:"
        reportArray(row, 2) = questionArray(j, 2)
        reportArray(row, 4) = "Consequence:"
        reportArray(row, 6) = questionArray(j, 3)

        row += 1

        ' Divider line
        reportArray(row, 0) = "________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________"

        row += 1
    Next

    reportRange.Value = reportArray
End Sub
```

questionArray is the offender in this code.

Comment: What language is your code?  VBA requires constants when declaring a variable, at least in the version on my computer.

Comment: I used the wrong tag, This is Visual Basic not vba using the .net framework

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are declaring `questionArray` and `reportArray` as objects, however you are treating them like variables. Change your declaration statements to

```
Dim questionArray as variant
Dim reportArray(maxPrintableRow + 1, 10) As String
```

Comment: questionArray holds Strings, however using: 

`Dim questionArray(maxQuestions, 7) As String`

Causes:

`questionArray = questionRange.Value`

to fail with the error:

Unable to cast object of type 'System.Object[,]' to type 'System.String[,]'.

Comment: Then change `Integer` to `String`, also I have updated my answer

Comment: I apologize, I entered that comment before it was complete. I've updated it with my full message

Comment: Oops my mistake. Use `variant` for for `questionArray` and `String` for `reportArray`. I have updated my answer

Comment: It turns out that 'Dim questionArray As Object' is fine, the issue I was running into was that even though the debugger showed value at (0,0) the array was actually starting at (1,1). That's apparently a weird behavior on the Visual Studio Debuggers part